# Upgrade check an existing Indexdb to a newer version

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

What are the method available to check if client `IndexedDb` require an update or not? This for users who already have  existing local storage

```
var idx_db = null;
var dbRequest = window.indexedDB.open(“ExampleDB”);
    dbRequest.onerror = function (evt) {
    alert(“Db error: “ + evt.target.error.name);
}
    dbRequest.onsuccess = function (evt) {
    idx_db = evt.target.result; 
}
```

Comment: also see https://web.dev/indexeddb/#versioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure out from [HTML5-IndexedDB](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920015116.do) book.  By specify  a version number that is higher than the current database version of the database which will trigger the `onupgradeneeded` event handler.

```
var dbRequest = window.indexedDB.open(“ExampleDB”, 2);
dbRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (evt) {
if (evt.oldVersion < 1) {
      // create objects for version 1
}
    // other version upgrade paths
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to check anything. The only thing you need to do is opening the indexeddb with the required version like:

```
var db = window.indexedDB.open("db", 3);
```

If an upgrade is needed, the onupgradeneeded callback will be called. If the database is allready in the current version, only the success callback will be called.

Inside the onupgradeneeded callback, you can check what the oldversion of the database is. With this you can choose the upgrade path that is needed.